# Replace text within variable in Bash

Tags: bash, curl

I am saving a Curl response into a variable here:

```
results=$(curl -username:password "URL/api/search/dates?dateFields=created&from=${Three_Months_Ago}&today&repos=generic-sgca" | jq -r '.results[].uri')
echo "$results"
```

which returns the following:

```
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Lastest_Deploy.tar
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-0.0.5/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-1-linux-x64-installer.run
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-0.0.5/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-1-windows-installer.exe
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-0.0.99/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-1-linux-x64-installer.run
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-0.0.99/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-1-windows-installer.exe
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-0.2.0/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-2-linux-x64-installer.run
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-0.2.0/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-2-windows-installer.exe
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-100.0.0/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-2-linux-x64-installer.run
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-100.0.0/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-2-windows-installer.exe
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-101.0.0/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-2-linux-x64-installer.run
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-101.0.0/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-2-windows-installer.exe
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-99.9.9/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-2-linux-x64-installer.run
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-99.9.9/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-2-windows-installer.exe
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-99.9.91/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-2-linux-x64-installer.run
URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Installer-Deploy-99.9.91/SignalStudioPro-Alpha-2-windows-installer.exe
```

In each of these lines, I need to remove the "/api/storage" part of the URL. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: The simple answer is: don't store a multiline response in a  single variable; see Bash FAQ 001 as I mentioned your previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "${results//\/api\/storage/}"
```

would do what you're asking, but there is probably no good reason to capture the result in a variable just to print it. Maybe you're better off with

```
curl ... | jq ... | sed 's=/api/storage=='
```

or figuring out how to do the subsititution as part of your `jq` script.

Comment: I was able to get it with adding the |sed 's=/api/storage==' to the end of my curl command. I think I got it working now, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

With [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
echo "${results//\/api\/storage}"
```